# Where to add default value in CreateAPIView?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a `ListCreateAPIView`, on which I want to populate a field with a default value in case of not provided by request.DATA.

Problem is: where should I do that ?

I can't modify the `request.DATA` because it is immutable and I don't want to copy/paste the `CreateMixin` implementation.

Here is my code:

```
class ObjectiveList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    model = Objective
    serializer_class = ObjectiveSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        # provide a default value
        objective_definition_id = request.DATA.get('objective_definition',-1)
        data = request.DATA.copy()
        if objective_definition_id == -1:
            # support for 0.9.1 version of iOS and below
            logger.info(str(self.request.DATA))
            mission_url = request.DATA["mission"]
            objectivedefinition_pk = self.default_objectivedefinition_id(mission_url)
            data["objective_definition"]=objectivedefinition_pk

        # I would want to do something like this but I can't
        # request.DATA = data
        # super(ObjectiveList,self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)

        # copy/paste of the super class implementation
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data, files=request.FILES)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            self.pre_save(serializer.object)
            self.object = serializer.save(force_insert=True)
            self.post_save(self.object, created=True)
            headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                    headers=headers)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Here is my serializer:

```
class ObjectiveSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    objective_definition = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=False, read_only=False, required=False, default=toto)

    class Meta:
        model = Objective
        fields = (
            'url',
            'objective_definition',
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `default=` argument on the field, don't know if that meets your use case?

Comment: You mean `default=` here: http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields.html#core-arguments? I'll try that. In the mean time I've edited my question with more details.

Comment: It looks like there is no `default` for `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`.

Comment: It does accept a `default` argument, just like all the other fields. I've not double checked if it's used if you don't supply any data. If you can supply a pull request that contains a failing test then I'd look into getting any defects fixed.

Comment: Here is the pull request https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/pull/1091